# Question on how shared memory works in Python's multi programming library

Tags: python, multiprogramming

I'm sure this has been answered before but I'd love to understand why this is occurring. My guess is its either something to do with Python's pass-by-object-reference attribute or something with shared memory.

Why when I dynamically change the self.size variable in ThreadSafeInt does it not update the copy owned by all other threads?

Output:

```
Value = 10
Value = 10
Value = 20
Done!
```

main.py

```
def change(num):
     num.setNum(20)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
     import sys
     num = ThreadSafeInt.ThreadSafeInt()
     num.setNum(10)
     print("Value = " + str(num.get()))
     #Changing value in different thread
     p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=change, args=(num,)) 
     p3.start()
     p3.join()
     print("Value = " + str(num.get()))
     #Changing the value in same thread
     num.setNum(20)
     print("Value = " + str(num.get()))
     print("Done!")
```

ThreadSafeInt.py

```
import multiprocessing

class ThreadSafeInt:
     def __init__(self):
          self.size = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
          self.lock = multiprocessing.RLock()

     def get(self):
          with self.lock:
               return self.size.value
     def setNum(self, num):
          with self.lock:
               self.size = multiprocessing.Value('i', num)
```

Comment: You are changing a value of an instance, e.g. something declared inside init, those belong to the object not to the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setNum` function when you set your new value you're defining a new `Value` object, so you're not modifying the existing one.
If you change your code to:

```
class ThreadSafeInt:
     def __init__(self):
          self.size = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
          self.lock = multiprocessing.RLock()

     def get(self):
          with self.lock:
               return self.size.value
     def setNum(self, num):
          with self.lock:
               self.size.value = num   <--- change this line
```

it will work.

```
Output:
Value = 10
Value = 20
Value = 20
Done!
```